# Exception with get_script c++ 6.0

Tags: javascript, c++

I am experiencing problems using the `get_script` method in C++ 6.0 and running the application in a Windoxs XP with IE 8. No problem with the compilation. At run time I always get an exception.

Other methods like `get_all`, `get_Scripts` and `get_tagname` work fine. The problem is only with this method, but I have to use it to run a javascript code from C++.

My question is what can be wrong with my code:

```
try{
  lpDispatch = GetHtmlDocument();
  if(lpDispatch==NULL) 
  {
    log.LogError("Actions::lpDispatch a NULL");
    return;
  }
  ASSERT(lpDispatch);

  hr=lpDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&lpHtmlDocument2);
  log.LogDebug("QueryInterface() result ", hr);

  if((hr!=S_OK) || (lpHtmlDocument==NULL)) 
  {
    log.LogError("Actions::lpHtmlDocument a NULL"); 
    return;
  }
  ASSERT(lpHtmlDocument);
  log.LogDebug("----------------------- TESTE JSCRIPT BEGIN --------------------------------");

  OLECHAR * bstrMember =L"LocalSubmit()";

  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X --------------------------"); 

  CComPtr<IHTMLElement> spElement;
  BSTR bstr;
  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- 0");
  hr = lpHtmlDocument2->get_activeElement(&spElement);
  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- 01");
  spElement->get_tagName(&bstr);
  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- 02");
  log.LogDebug(bstr);

  IDispatch* pDisp = NULL;

  if(lpHtmlDocument2 == NULL)
  {
    log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- ERRO");
  }

  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- 04");
  hr = lpHtmlDocument2->get_Script(&pDisp);
  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- 05");
  if(FAILED(hr))
  {
    log.LogDebug("GetIDsOfNames(2) Invoke", hr);
  }
  else
    log.LogDebug("GetIDsOfNames(2) Sucess");

  log.LogDebug("----------------------- X -- 1", hr);
  ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
  DISPID dispid = NULL;
  hr = spScript->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL,&bstrMember,1,LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,&dispid);
  if(FAILED(hr))
  {
    log.LogDebug("GetIDsOfNames(2) Invoke", hr);
  }
  else
    log.LogDebug("GetIDsOfNames(2) Sucess");
}
catch (...)
{
  log.LogError("Actions:: EXCEPTION ");
}
```

We get the following output:

```
DEBUG: ----------------------- TESTE JSCRIPT BEGIN --------------------------------
DEBUG: ----------------------- X --------------------------
DEBUG: ----------------------- X -- 0
DEBUG: ----------------------- X -- 01
DEBUG: ----------------------- X -- 02
DEBUG: BODY
DEBUG: ----------------------- X -- 04
ERROR: Actions:: EXCEPTION
```

Best regards,
Miguel